# Where can I download Groovy Grails Tool Suite version 3.5.1 for Windows?

Tags: eclipse, grails, ggts

The download page at SpringSource (http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all) doesn't seem to make previous versions of GGTS available, but I want to have this version to be able to toggle between the Groovy 2.0.7 and Groovy 2.1.8 compilers.

As a potential solution, I searched for mirrors, but was unable to find any. In addition, I also checked GitHub for the GGTS source for this release so I could compile it myself, but I didn't find that either.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the version directly in the URL so this one should work:

http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.5.1/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32-x86_64.zip

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The GGTS 3.5.1 32bit version is here:

http://download.springsource.com/release/STS/3.5.1/dist/e4.4/groovy-grails-tool-suite-3.5.1.RELEASE-e4.4-win32.zip

It has grails-2.3.8, tomcat 6 and 7.